# Difference Between Reference Sign After Data Type or Before Variable Name?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if the position of the 'reference sign' (**&**) matters when referencing a variable.

Such as...

```
vector<int>& v;
vector<int> &v;
```

Is there a difference at all, or is it really just preference?

Comment: Use clang-format and never worry about this :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's totally preference, but I like to keep the & next to the type when I'm declaring a variable or specifying a parameter. That way, when I'm referencing a variable and use `&my_variable`, I know just by looking at it that it's a variable reference and has nothing to do with a declaration. I do the same thing with pointers. I declare them `int* ptr;` so that way when I see `*ptr` I know it's just dereferencing it.

Answer (score 1):

Totally preference, it's only the order that's important.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use:

```
vector<int>&v;
vector<int> & v;
```

without any problem. From the compiler's point of view there can be no space or any number of spaces between `vector<int>` and `&`, and between `&` and `v`.

Where you use spaces and how many spaces you use depends entirely on your coding standards.